# NcML aggregation of remote THREDDS catalog

Tags: netcdf, thredds, ncml

I want to aggregate all files within a specific directory of a remote THREDDS catalog. These are `grib2` files for nam forecast. [This](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/thredds/catalog/nam218/catalog.html) is the main list of directories for each month. Here is my `ncml` file for the aggregation of [this catalog](https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/thredds/catalog/nam218/201807/20180723/catalog.html) of files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<netcdf xmlns="http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/namespaces/netcdf/ncml-2.2" >
    <aggregation dimName="time" type="joinExisting">
    <scan location="http://www.ncei.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/nam218/201807/20180723/" regExp="^.*\.grb2$" subdirs="false"/>
    <dimension name="time" orgName="t" />
    </aggregation>
</netcdf>
```

Also, I am mostly interested in having these two variables in the files: `u-component_of_wind_height_above_ground` and `v-component_of_wind_height_above_ground`.

I am not sure the above aggregation is correct from the *remote* catalog. I get this error from the above ncml file:

> `There are no datasets in the aggregation DatasetCollectionManager{ collectionName='http://www.ncei.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/nam218/201807/20180723/^.*\.grb2$' recheck=null 
>    dir=http://www.ncei.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/nam218/201807/20180723/ filter=^.*\.grb2$`

How this `ncml` file should be written?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot glob remote URLs so you will need to provide a list of these OPeNDAP endpoints to the aggregation, like:

```
<dataset name="Nam218" urlPath="nam218">
  <netcdf xmlns="http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/namespaces/netcdf/ncml-2.2">
    <aggregation dimName="time" type="joinExisting">
      <netcdf location="http://www.ncei.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/nam218/201807/20180723/<file01>.grb2"/>
      <netcdf location="http://www.ncei.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/nam218/201807/20180723/<file02>.grb2"/>
      <netcdf location="http://www.ncei.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/nam218/201807/20180723/<file03>.grb2"/>
    </aggregation>
  </netcdf>
</dataset>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple program (I used c++) for use in the command prompt. (I use Windows.)  It launches a BAT file that launches wget and downloads the latest THREDDS catalog, then saves it in plain text, then the c++ program loads the entire file into a string where I parse it and do what I want with the data.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but that's not the question. If I wanted to download, then aggregate, I could simply use `netCDF4.MFDataset`  (one line does all you mentioned). The question is to use NCL, allowing to customize data on server side, _before_ downloading terabytes.